# counting occurrences in list of list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Why this does not work? I found the functions written under on Stack Overflow, but it still doesn't work.

I ideally want to find how many times the word occurs in the inner list and how many times all the words occurs in all the lists combined. So for 'das' - it occurs two times in the first list of the list and three times total:

```
from collections import Counter

from collections import defaultdict

import numpy

import operator

import pandas

a = [['das','sadad','asdas','das'],['das','sadad','da'],['aaa','8.9']]

def counter(a):
    return Counter(a)


def count(a):
    return dict((i, a.count(i)) for i in set(a))


def bincount(a):
    return numpy.bincount(a)


def pandas_value_counts(a):
    return pandas.Series(a).value_counts()


def occur_dict(a):
    d = {}
    for i in a:
        if i in d:
            d[i] = d[i]+1
        else:
            d[i] = 1
    return d


def count_unsorted_list_items(items):
    counts = defaultdict(int)
    for item in items:
        counts[item] += 1
    return dict(counts)


def operator_countof(a):
    return dict((i, operator.countOf(a, i)) for i in set(a))

occur_dict(a)
pandas_value_counts(a)
count_unsorted_list_items(a)
bincount(a)
count(a)
counter(a)
operator_countof(a)
```

---

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "it.py", line 45, in <module>
    occur_dict(a)
  File "it.py", line 28, in occur_dict
    if i in d:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: please include the full traceback. Don't leave us searching for the line that throws the exception

Comment: But, I've spotted it. What would you expect `Counter([['das','sadad','asdas','das'],['das','sadad','da'],['aaa','8.9']])` to return?

Comment: Don't copy code off the internet that you don't understand. You copied ***7*** counting routines and tried to run all of them at once, and it doesn't sound like you understood any one of them or the fact that these were 7 different options, not one combined solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have some list of lists `a`.  We want to get counts for each of the sublists, and the total of those counts.  Note that the total counts will just be the sum of the counts of the sublists.

```
from collections import Counter

a = [['das','sadad','asdas','das'],['das','sadad','da'],['aaa','8.9']]

def count(list_of_lists):
    counts = [Counter(sublist) for sublist in list_of_lists]
    total_count = sum(counts, Counter())
    return counts, total_count
```

Now if we want the counts of `das` in the first sublist and the number of `das` across all sublists we can do

```
counts, total = count(a)
print(counts[0]['das'])
# 2
print(total['das'])
# 3
```